# Recursive type not working for nested objects with unknown fields

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a recursive type (`Foo`) for a nested object with unknown fields:

```
interface Foo {
  [key: string]: number | Foo;
}

const foo: Foo = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: 2,
    d: {
      e: 3,
      f: 3
      // etc...
    }
  }
};

const bar = foo.b.d;
```

With the code above I get an error on the last line:

```
Property 'd' does not exist on type 'number | Foo'.
  Property 'd' does not exist on type 'number'.ts(2339)
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work and how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

The type of `foo.b` is `number | Foo`. Typescript here is preventing you from trying to access field `d` (or any field) on a `number`.

You need to assert that `foo.b` is actually a `Foo` and not a `number` or change the type of your object.

If you know for certain that it is a `Foo` then `const bar = (foo.b as Foo).d` should do the trick. Otherwise moving it into an if statement while narrowing the type with a `typeof` check to make sure it `!= number`.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I didn't know `(foo.b as Foo).d` was possible. The only drawback is that it won't work with deeper chains, e.g. `foo.b.d.e` . Any idea how to make deeper chains possible, without breaking the code up with `if / typeof`, etc.?

Comment: Without knowing your use case it is hard to suggest a more appropriate answer other than "turning off" the type checking temporarily with `const bar = (foo as any).b.d as number`. But know you are now opting out of typechecking and just saying "trust me typescript, this is ok".